# Minizinc: counting occurrences in an array based on matches to a second array, outputting in 2d array

Tags: arrays, minizinc

The next wall I'm hitting is trying to count occurrences within an array, on the condition that they match values in another array.

I would like to combine the following model

```
set of int: OPTS = 1..4;
set of int: ASSIGN = 1..12;

array[ASSIGN] of var OPTS: result;
```

with these statements

```
enum CONDS = {A,B,C,D};
array[ASSIGN] of CONDS : const = [A,A,A,B,B,B,C,C,C,D,D,D];

array[OPTS,CONDS] of var int: result2;

output ["\(result) \(show2d(result2))"]
```

and produce an output that tallies for each `OPTS` how many times each of the `CONDS` appear, something like

`[ 1,2,1,3,3,4,1,3,1,2,2,4 ] [|2,0,2,0|1,0,0,2|0,2,1,0|0,1,0,1]`

Namely, `OPTS[1]` has 2 A `CONDS`, 0 B `CONDS` and 2 C `CONDS` and 0 D `CONDS`, while `OPTS[2]` has 1 A `CONDS`, 0 B `CONDS`, 0 C `CONDS` and 2 D `CONDS`, and so on.

I don't know how many combinations of the following I've gone through but none of it is producing the expected results, despite what I think should be logical.

```
constraint forall(i in OPTS,j in CONDS)(
     result2[i,j] = 
       sum(k in result)(% tried all sorts of things here with i,j, and k and if statements)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a model that for each value in `OPTS` count the number of occurrences in `CONDS`. The tricky part is the `count` construct where one have to check that the value in `result` is the `OPTS` value `o`. This is done with `count` constraint, where `(result[i]==0)` is the condition that this value in `result[i]` is the `o` we want, and then we check what `COND` it belongs to (`const[i]`).

```
include "globals.mzn";

set of int: OPTS = 1..4;
set of int: ASSIGN = 1..12;

% Note: hard coded with the example from the question.
array[ASSIGN] of var OPTS: result = [ 1,2,1,3,3,4,1,3,1,2,2,4 ];

enum CONDS = {A,B,C,D};
array[ASSIGN] of CONDS : const = [A,A,A,B,B,B,C,C,C,D,D,D];

% count the number of occurences in each chunk
array[OPTS,CONDS] of var 0..max(ASSIGN): result2;

constraint 
   % for each integer in OPTS
   %     count the number of occurrences of each c in CONDS
   forall(o in OPTS) (
       forall(c in CONDS) (
           result2[o,c] = count([const[i]*(result[i] == o) | i in ASSIGN],c)
       )
   )
;

solve satisfy;

output [
    "const: \(const)\n",
    "result: \(result)\n",
    "result2: ", show2d(result2), "\n",
];
```

The output of the model with the hardcoded `result` from your example is:

```
const: [A, A, A, B, B, B, C, C, C, D, D, D]
result: [1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 4]
result2: [| 2, 0, 2, 0 |
   1, 0, 0, 2 |
   0, 2, 1, 0 |
   0, 1, 0, 1 |]
```

**Edit:**
Instead of the count loop, one can instead use the global constraint which should be a little more efficient `global_cardinality`. It use the same idea as the `count` version but is wrapped in a single `forall` loop:

```
constraint 
   forall(o in OPTS) (
       global_cardinality([const[i]*(result[i] == o) | i in ASSIGN],OPTS,result2[o,..])
   )
;
```

Comment: That's great, thanks! Will have a couple of questions to help my properly understand what's going on. First, does `0..max(ASSIGN)` simply reduce the range vs using `int`, potentially making it quicker?

Comment: You've used the format `count([ function | range ], something )`, how would that look using the `count(i in x)(i=c) <= d` format suggested in the documentation? `count( range )( function ) something`?

Comment: 1) I don't understand the first question, but the full range of 0..12 is needed if we don't know more about the structure of `result`. `max(ASSIGN)` is reduced to 12 if that is what you're wonder.

Comment: 2) `count(i in ASSIGN) (const[i]*(result[i] == o) = c )`. Personally, I generally prefer using constraints with array comprehension since it's clearer (to me at least). It shouldn't be any difference in performance.

Comment: Now, as it turns out, what I'm actually looking for is the number of different `CONDS` that appear for each `OPTS`. I presume it needn't be found by going through the above `forall` constraint, and it seems to have similarities to my earlier questions, but it's just about different enough to stop me from seeing the trick. The 1d array statement would be `array[OPTS] of var 0..max(CONDS): count;` (I guess) and output for `count` based on `result` would be `[2,2,2,2]`

Comment: Please write this as a new question.